# android:overScrollMode="never" does not work in the quasar capacitor project

Tags: android, vue.js, capacitor, quasar

I want to disable the screen stretching effect when I try to scroll at the top of the screen.

Added to the file src-capacitor\android\app\src\main\res\layout\activity_main.xml

```
 <ScrollView
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
 android:overScrollMode="never">
```

but the effect remains the same. Am I missing something? Is the file wrong or the entry is incorrect?

Comment: Maybe you have another scrolling view in the layout, that may overscroll efect (like `RecyclerView`)?

Comment: Thanks for the suggested option, but it didn't help either. I would have thought it was the wrong file, but it had a WebView and
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="match_parent" .
I have added RecyclerView, ScrollView, androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView. I added it wherever I could
         android:overScrollMode="never", but it didn't help.